# Replace an item in a list based on user input

Tags: python, string

I'm a noob so please excuse me.

There are three lists

1. A list of letters L = ['A','B','C','D','E']
2. A list of numbers N = ['1','2','3','4','5']
3. A list of number strings List = ['124','351']

These are the steps I wish to achieve

1. Request a letter from the user e.g. A
2. Find the letter in the letter list **L** and record its numerical position e.g. [0]
3. Use the same numeric position in the list of numbers **N** and record the
   number that's there e.g. 1
4. Replace the instances of the number found in the non-letter strings **List** e.g. ['124','351'] becomes ['A24','35A']
5. Ask the user for the next letter until all the number strings become letters.

What I have achieved so far is the first 4 steps. After step 4 I thought to check if the number strings still contained numbers and if so go to step 5.  I can't seem to work out how to get the code to check if the number strings contain any more number.  NOTE: The number list is not limited to numbers.  It could contain math symbols e.g. + or -

```
L = ['A','B','C','D','E']
N = ['1','2','3','4','5']
list = ['124','351']

print ("Enter a letter")

# Is there a number in List
# If yes then do the following else print List

# Ask for a letter from the user
letter = input ("Enter letter: ")

# Confirm whether the letter is correct or not
if letter in L:
# Find the position of the letter in the list
    position = (L.index(letter));
# Make a variable called number with value at the same position in the N list
    number = N[position];
# Replace the numbers in the List with the letter entered
    list = [item.replace(number, letter) for item in list];
# Print the list with the numbers replaced
    print (list, "\n");
    print ("Please guess again. \n");
    letter = input ("Enter a letter now: ")
# repeat until the List only contains letters
else:
    print ("That is not correct");
    print ("Please guess again. \n");
    letter = input ("Enter a letter now: ")
```

I hope that is OK.  If you need anything further please let me know

Comment: Just use a `while` loop and get user input after checking if the list has numbers. Also never use `input()` if you're using python 2, use `raw_input()`.

Comment: @AbdulFatir: how do you know the OP isn't using Python 3?  Plus: the English word *is* `letters`.  "Alphabets" are sets of letters, like "Latin alphabet" or "Greek alphabet" or "Phoenician alphabet".

Comment: soo when does the process stops

Comment: I'm using IDLE to write the code. I downloaded from the Python.org site a few days ago so I am unsure about your comment regarding the OP?

Comment: I have tried various permutations of while, for etc and cannot get it to work.  I cannot get the code to check the list to see if it contains numbers or non-letters such as + or -.  My goal is for it to contain letters only.  I understand the raw_input comment thanks and will ensure I follow your suggestion but I do not understand the alphabet remark. Cheers

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ The process stops after showing the list with the 1 replaced by A and then requests "Enter a letter now:"

Comment: ```list``` is a Python *built-in* function name.  It is a bad idea to use these function name's as variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L = ['A','B','C','D','E']
N = ['1','2','3','4','5']
n_strings = ['124','351'] # Don't use list as a variable name

while not all( x.isalpha() for x in n_strings): # keep going until all are alpha chars

    print ("Enter a letter")
    # Is there a number in List
    # If yes then do the following else print List

    # Ask for a letter from the user
    letter = input("Enter letter: ")

    # Confirm whether the letter is correct or not
    if letter in L:
    # Find the position of the letter in the list
        position = (L.index(letter));
    # Make a variable called number with value at the same position in the N list
        number = N[position];
    # Replace the numbers in the List with the letter entered
        n_strings = [item.replace(number, letter) for item in n_strings];
    # Print the list with the numbers replaced
        print (n_strings, "\n");
        print ("Please guess again. \n");
        letter = input("Enter a letter now: ")
    # repeat until the List only contains letters
    else:
        print ("That is not correct");
        print ("Please guess again. \n");
        letter = input("Enter a letter now: ")
```

You could change the logic and shorten the code.

```
while True:
    if all(x.isalpha() for x in n_strings ):
        print("All guessed correct {}".format(n_strings)) # if all are alpha print final n_string and break out of loop
        break
    print n_strings    
    letter = input("Please enter a letter: ")
    if letter in L:
    # Find the position of the letter in the list
        position = (L.index(letter));
        number = N[position];
        n_strings = [item.replace(number, letter) for item in n_strings];
        print (n_strings, "\n");
    # repeat until the List only contains letters
    else:
        print ("That is not correct");
        print ("Please guess again. \n");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I used the first of your two answers as it was the closest to my own code and I want to understand the options I had but I will be trying your other code anyway.  I am here to learn! :-)

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. The second example is tidier and finishes cleaner than the first.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't seem to work out how to get the code to check if the number
>   strings contain any more number

You could define a function that loops over the list to see if any of the entries have digits using using [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) like so

```
def has_number(lst):
    for s in lst:
        if any(x.isdigit() for x in s):
            return True
    return False
```

This will return True if any of the entries in your number string list contains a number

---

Saw your edit

> My goal is for it to contain letters only

To do that you could just check like this

```
if all(x.isalpha() for x in lst):
    # lst contains only entries that consists of letters
```

This uses [isalpha()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)

> **str.isalpha()**
>
> Return true if all characters in the string are
>   alphabetic and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

Demonstration:

```
>>> all(x.isalpha() for x in ['abc', 'def'])
True
>>> all(x.isalpha() for x in ['ab1', 'def'])
False
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the advice but the list may also contain other math characters such as + or -.  I assume isdigit will not work for that?

Comment: Cool, I'm going to try this now.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.  As with the chap above, I am learning a heap and your support was gratefully received.  Its very kind of you :-)